# Супер-AirPods/Супер'AirPods

Tags: заимствования, дефис, приставка, апостроф

Немного непонятно, как писать русские приставки с английскими словами. Возможно, отделяются апострофом, как и суффикс с окончанием, а может, нет. Можете подсказать, как написать, например, *`супер()AirPods`*?

Comment: Вопрос: а зачем? В правилах отсутствуют какие-либо рекомендации на этот счёт.

Comment: Интересно — вот зачем.